# Angular How to protect a route that has an id in it and anybody can guess it?

Tags: angular

I have an Angular 4 app that relies on using parameters that I than use to fetch information (i.e. a route that is `/project/:id` `/project/1` the problem is this isnt secure because any user can guess the number. I am taking precaution by verifying on the backend that the person requesting it is the owner of the data being retrieved.

Since I'm checking on the backend the user can still enter `project/310` and if it that project doesnt belong to them no data will be returned but the user will still see the HTML page.

I've thought of using session storage to store the `id` and than in the component check and see if its present if not redirect.

If anybody has a better/more efficient way to do this I would appreciate it.

Comment: Which version of angular are you using?

Comment: Angular 4. Sorry I've updated the OP

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need a **Route Guard**

```
import { AngularFireAuth } from 'angularfire2/auth';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Router,  ActivatedRouteSnapshot, RouterStateSnapshot, CanActivate } from '@angular/router';
@Injectable()
export class AuthGuard implements CanActivate {
  loggedIn = false;

  constructor(private dummyService: DummyService, private router: Router) {
  }
  canActivate( route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,  state: RouterStateSnapshot) {
   //To get the data in the url for instance,'product/1'
   const productId = route.params.id; 
   //here get the data and do the necessary logic
  return this.dummyService.SomeFunction
      .map( authState => !!authState) need to return a boolean
      .do( auth => {
            //user is not the owner of the data so redirect them somewhere else
          if (!auth) {
            this.router.navigate(['/login']);
          }
            //if you got here, then the user is the owner of the data.
      }).take(1);
      }
    }
```

In your routing, add this

```
  {
    path: 'product/:id',
    component: SomeComponent,
    canActivate: [AuthGuard ]
  }
```

And add `AuthGuard` in your providers in app.module.

More info:

CanActivate - https://angular.io/api/router/CanActivate

Comment: The reason I dont want to do it this way is because I have about 10 components where I will have to do this so I'll need 10 different guards but I dont see any other way

Comment: @derrickrozay you can reuse route guards across components.  Just put `AuthGuard` in multiple routes.

Comment: @DerekBrown is correct. Let's say you have productdetailscomponent, you would do something like this {
    path: 'productdetails/:id',
    component: ProductDetailsComponent,
    canActivate: [AuthGuard ]
  }
and still uses the same authguard i answered

Comment: I see. The only problem is that if I have 10 routes I will have to call my API on each one to check if they are the owner

Comment: @derrickrozay at first it may seemed redundant but think about it if you will only check it once? what if you changed something to the database like you want to remove the privelege of that user? Checking it everytime is actually good in my opinion if you really want that security. or change the auth guard not to call the api and call it somewhere else like from another service where you will call the api once.